# master page implementation in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i am using vb-2008 to create my application. i created master page in asp but i am not able to use it on other pages. i used :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Mail.Master" Inherits="webform1._Default" %>
```

i created master page as:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Mail.master.cs" Inherits="master1.Mail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="imghead" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/images1.jpeg" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but this is not showing master page on other page where it is implemented..
how can i implement the master page..

Comment: remove your `<asp:Image` from inside the Place Holder in the masterpage and add that into a new page that inherits the selected MasterPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you need to create ASPX pages that have the `masterpage` assigned and fill up the content placeholders

your new page called, for example, `default.aspx` will contain:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/Mail.Master" Inherits="webform1._Default" %>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <!-- Add code here to add to the HeadContent section -->
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!-- Add code here to add to the MainContent section -->
    <asp:Image ID="imghead" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/images1.jpeg" />
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

A `MasterPage` only holds the `PlaceHolders` for where other pages will inject content.

There is a hole Video on MasterPages that you can see here:

> [ASP.NET WebForms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms) Part 5: [**MasterPages**](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/players/PSODPlayer.aspx?author=dan-wahlin&name=webforms-05&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-webforms4-intro)