# What is the reason for jquery to perform only in the default page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

In my asp application, I have used several jqueries. Those are perfectly work in the default page. But not in any other pages. Someone please give me an idea why it is not performing?

Comment: We need way way more information before we can even attempt to solve this. How are they not working on the other pages? What is the relevant source code on each page? What about the javascript you're including? Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a master page that will be used by all of your pages and add the following codes

aspx :

```
<script src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/javascripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

aspx.cs :

```
    page_load(){
     Page.Header.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery on every page you want to use it on, you could do this easily by creating a master page and have all your pages use that master. See [master page implementation in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179125/master-page-implementation-in-asp-net)